# Customized object in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following CSS for a container that is suppose to site on top of an image at a given position:

```
.jumbotron .container {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top:75px;
}

.jumbotron .caption{
    position: static;
    max-width: 750px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.65) !important;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Which creates the following on the example site: [example development site](http://adambalan.com/WordPressDev/)

What your looking at is the giant jumbotron image with a opaque square over it. resize the screen down so that the menu goes into mobile friendly, everything looks relatively fine, now open the menu.

The opaque square does not move down with the image, it stays in one position. How do I get it to move with the image and retain its original position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to that specific jumbotron.